# Objective-C/Mac - Set Pixel Colour?

Tags: objective-c, macos, colors, pixel, paint

In my Mac application, I am letting the user paint on a grid, each square on the grid representing a pixel and having its own colour. Is it possible to then take that colour and simple one by one produce an image by setting the pixel colour?

I can't really think of how else to do this. I need to export an image once the user has painted into this grid that I am making.

Thanks.

*The aim of my app:
The user can paint into a grid. So the final image might be 16x16 pixels in size, however the user in the app can paint each pixel into a square of a grid (16x16). This is then outputted into the format of the final image which might be 16x16 pixels, literally on screen. While the grid visually while painting is larger. Each square on the grid represents a pixel in the final image, and the user can put a single colour into each square. Hopefully this makes sense, if not I shall try and elaborate and link an example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**TLDR:** Use [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1).]

There are three distinct things to consider here:

1. The "ideal" image that the user is drawing, a grid of 16x16 (or however many) coloured pixels.
2. The onscreen representation of it, where each pixel is displayed at much larger size for the user to interact with.
3. An eventual image file exported from the app.

Keeping those elements separate in your mind and your implementation will make your life a *lot* easier.

#1 is a **model**, and in this case will likely consist of an array of 256 (or however many) colour values, probably along with some descriptive data like the pixel dimensions and colour space. For something this simple you *might* not want to create a separate model class (although you should), but even if it's just an array ivar sitting in a monolithic app class you should still think of it as a distinct entity in its own right.

#2 is a **view** (with **controller** tendencies), and you should almost certainly implement it using a custom `NSView` subclass. It would be *possible* to build a grid of 256 instances of `NSColorWell` or some other existing `NSView` type, but that would just be *silly*. The view has two jobs:

1. Draw the model onscreen. Do this by iterating over the data values and drawing each one as a filled rectangle of an appropriate size. The methods of `NSBezierPath` are your friends here, especially the class methods `fillRect` and `strokeRect`.
2. Mediate user input. For example, you might decide that the user colours a pixel by clicking on it with the mouse. Your view will get sent an event for each mouse click, and will need to respond by mapping the click location to the correct pixel (basically a matter of division) and then making the appropriate changes to the model.

#3 is in some ways just another kind of view, in that it is another way of representing the model. Code for producing it is sometimes included with the model (say if there's only one canonical way of serialising the data), but it's good practice to put it somewhere else, especially if you might want to add other arbitrary mechanisms later.

The key here is that this image is really nothing to do with the `NSView` side of things, it's a matter of taking the model data and writing it out. You can do the writing via `NSImage` methods or via Core Graphics, as mentioned in the other answers, but what you *absolutely shouldn't* do is try to manhandle it directly off the screen. That way lies madness!

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much detail about how your user is drawing, but generally speaking you could think of converting your view into an image.

Try something along the line:

```
NSData *data;
NSBitmapImageRep *rep;
rep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[self frame]];
[self cacheDisplayInRect:[self frame] toBitmapImageRep:rep];
data = [rep TIFFRepresentation];
```

This should work if your view is not openGL.

EDIT:

Don't know if you have already solved this, but one approach could be displaying a 16/16 grid of transparent `NSButtons`. When you click on one button, you change its color (or allow the user to choose one).

When the user is done, either you build a 16x16 pixel bitmap "by hand" (setting its pixel to the corresponding button color), or you save the image (with the method I outlined), and scale it down.

Buttons are not strictly necessary; you could override the [`hitTest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest%3a) method in your `NSView` and detect from the touch coordinate which area of the view to color.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to get my head around how the user can draw still. These two things sort of go hand in hand, so its tricky. If I was to use your approach above to create the image, how would you recommend the user paints these squares in a grid like fashion? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you mean by painting squares in a grid like fashion? I am sorry, but I can imagine many different things by it... If you like, you can add to this info to your question above...

Comment: No worries, I have tried to explain in the OP, but let me know if your a little fuzzy and I probably haven't done a good job explaining.

Comment: An easier way of putting it perhaps: I want a 16 x 16 grid of squares. These squares the user can change the colour of, then once finished editing the colours, the user can output this as a 16x16 pixel image. Any recommendations of methods?

Comment: @walkytalky: thank you! Anyway, I had luck because both NSButton and hitTest are available for Cocoa, so the approach is still valid.

Comment: I have tried this using NSButtons and filling them with a colour upon certain mouse events (down and entered). However on lower end macs, e.g 11" Macbook Air there is far to much lag.

Answer (score 0):

Your image can be a buffer of width*height*3 bytes (`char`). Normally row-first order is used, so the pixel at coordinates (x,y) corresponds to the three bytes starting at `(width*y+x)*3`. These three bytes will contain the red, green and blue components of that pixel's color, respectively. Initially you can set all bytes to 255 for a white background.

When you want to color the pixel at (x,y) with the color (r,g,b), you can do

```
i = (width*y+x)*3;
buf[i] = r;
buf[i+1] = g;
buf[i+2] = b;
```

If you want to work on your image using Quartz graphics calls, you can create a CGContext wrapping it using `CGBitmapContextCreate`. However, for changing the color of individual pixels writing the corresponding bytes directly is the fastest approach. It's also important that you understand how raster images are represented in memory, so it's a double win.